# Mount is not showing up when it is defined in cloud-config.yaml

Tags: linux, coreos

I am new to CoreOS and trying to mount an attached external HD on startup. I am using cloud-config to setup my machine, and my cloud-config.yaml file looks like this.

```
#cloud-config

# include one or more SSH public keys
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa xxxxxx

coreos:
  units:
    - name: media-data.mount
      command: start
      content: |
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/md126
        Where=/media/data
        Type=ext4
```

Why is my mount not showing up in /media/data? When I create an empty directory in /media/data and mount using

```
mount /dev/md126 /media/data
```

I am succesfully able to access the data stored on the external HD.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).